# Can a user's home folder files on windows be accessed from a dual-booted operating system?

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, file-permissions

I have files, like private keys, stored in my home folder on Windows 10:

```
C:\Users\Me\.ssh\id_rsa
```

Is this file readable from a dual booted/USB booted OS like Ubuntu?

Comment: You can make it readable if you mount the Windows partition inside Ubuntu. If you don't want it to be readable (not clear what the intention behind the question is) for security reasons, configure Ubuntu to don't mount it.

Comment: @dirkt I asked because I wanted to know if someone can get my private keys stored in my home folder without logging in as my user for e.g. use a USB-bootable ubuntu's file explorer to see ~/.ssh/id_rsa without respecting windows-imposed access controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone is able to plug in something into your PC's USB port, and then boot your computer, then yes, he'll be able to see all your files.

It doesn't really matter what kind of software he uses.

If your PC is in an environment where you need to protect yourself against this happening, encrypt your harddisk (or parts of your harddisk). Then in addition he'll have to know the password.

Answer (score 1):

You should always consider that if a bad actor has your machine in their possession that all unencrypted data is compromised.